# Define matrix : 'A' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this function in python that given a value and I would have a square matrix with random values.
But executing the procedure gives me the following error:
`A' is not defined`

How do I do that?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as spstats
import scipy.linalg as la
import random



def generaMatrice(n):
for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(n-1):    

            A[i][j]= random.randint(1,100) 



AI=np.linalg.inv(A)

return A, AI

A, AI = generaMatrice(n)
print(A)
print(AI)
L,U,P=calcoloLU(A)
X = calcolaInv(L,U,P)#INVERSA CALCOLATA CON LU 
I=np.asmatrix(np.eye(n)) #metti n

print(X)

resRel = (la.norm(np.dot(A,X)-I,2))/(la.norm(I,2))        
errRel = la.norm(X-AI,2)/la.norm(AI,2)

nCond = la.norm(A,2)*la.norm(X,2)
maggErr = nCond*resRel
```

Comment: Your code is not formatted properly. Can you please copy-paste the code into your question, highlight the code, and use the `{}` code formatting tool above the textarea (or press Ctrl-k).

Comment: In `generaMatrix` you try to set `A[i][j]=...`, but you never created an `A` array of the right shape.  That's where it's complaining about `A` not defined, right?  If you define a 2d array, `A[i,j]=...` is the best way of addressing an element.  But you don't need to do that since `randint` lets you specify a `shape`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some general errors with the formatting of your code, e.g. the first return statement is out of scope of the `generaMatrice` function.
Having said that, you can just do

```
A=np.random.randint(1,100,(n,n))
AI=np.linalg.inv(A)
```

and get rid of your `generaMatrice` function altogether. Numpy is neat because it allows you to create complex matrices with simple calls.

In general, remember that when you define functions, you need to **indent the content** of the function like so:

```
def generaMatrice(n):
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(n-1):    
            A[i][j]= random.randint(1,100) 
     AI=np.linalg.inv(A)
     return A,AI
```